# Sharing child project dll to parent project Code when running independently to parent project

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have 2 projects in my solution, When I run them together they run correctly. But I have to integrate it to other PC where I am giving Parent app code and child app dll. How this would be achieved ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It is done and is very easy.
Step 1 build child project dll 
Step 2 copy it from bin\Debug folder to parent project Asset Folder
Step 3 Add child project dll from Asset folder as existing object in to your Parent project.
All Done

Now if we run only parent project that will run successfully. If any one has any other way please post I will try them too.